# Building basic calculator with tkinter using Python. Confusion in passing a return value between classes

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

My task is to build basic calculator with GUI (`tkinter`) implementing OOP concepts.
There are 2 main classes that forms the calculator which is `LCDScreen` and `Button` class.
`LCDScreen` is responsible for all calculations processing, validation processing and displaying on the `Entry` in the `tkinter` interface while the button class is responsible to assign value to be displayed on the interface and to pass on the value to `LCDScreen`.

I don't know how to pass the return value from the btn_click while clicking a button instance and send it to the screen instance.

```
from tkinter import *

def btn_click(value):
print(value)
return value

digit_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "0", "."]
operator_list = ["+", "-", "x", "/"]
functional_command_list = ["AC", "<", "="]

#Entry interface
calculator = Tk()
calculator.title("Calculator")
e = Entry(calculator, width= 40, borderwidth= 5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=5)

class LCDScreen():
    operator = ""
    number = ""
    functional_command = ""


    def __init__(self, btn_value):
        if btn_value in digit_list:
            self.number = btn_value
            self.receiver(self.number)
            return
        else:
            if btn_value in operator_list:
                self.operator = btn_value
                self.receiver(self.operator)
                return
            else:
                if btn_value in functional_command_list:
                    self.functional_command = btn_value
                    self.receiver(self.functional_command)
                    return
                else:
                    print("Invalid input")

    def receiver(btn_value):
        received_value = btn_value
        print("Receiver function called")
        return received_value


    def clear():
        pass

    def equal():
        pass

    def add():
        pass

    def minus():
        pass

    def multiply():
        pass

    def divide():
        pass



#Define NumberButton class
class NumberButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw['width'] = 1
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.grid(ipadx=110, ipady=4)


#Define FunctionalButton class
class FunctionalButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw['width'] = 7
        kw['fg'] = 'black'

    
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.grid(ipadx=110, ipady=4)

    
#Instantiate LCDScreen Object
screen = LCDScreen(btn_click())
print(screen.receiver())

#Instantiate Number Button Object
btn_1 = NumberButton(calculator, text="1", command= lambda: btn_click("1"))
btn_1.grid(row=4, column=0)

btn_2 = NumberButton(calculator, text="2", command= lambda: btn_click("2"))
btn_2.grid(row=4, column=1)

btn_3 = NumberButton(calculator, text="3", command= lambda: btn_click("3"))
btn_3.grid(row=4, column=2)

btn_4 = NumberButton(calculator, text="4", command= lambda: btn_click("4"))
btn_4.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn_5 = NumberButton(calculator, text="5", command= lambda: btn_click("5"))
btn_5.grid(row=3, column=1)

btn_6 = NumberButton(calculator, text="6", command= lambda: btn_click("6"))
btn_6.grid(row=3, column=2)

btn_7 = NumberButton(calculator, text="7", command= lambda: btn_click("7"))
btn_7.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn_8 = NumberButton(calculator, text="8", command= lambda: btn_click("8"))
btn_8.grid(row=2, column=1)

btn_9 = NumberButton(calculator, text="9", command= lambda: btn_click("9"))
btn_9.grid(row=2, column=2)

btn_0 = NumberButton(calculator, text="0", command= lambda: btn_click("0"))
btn_0.grid(row=5, column=1) 

btn_decimal = NumberButton(calculator, text= ".", command=btn_click("."))
btn_decimal.grid(row=1, column= 2)

btn_clear = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "AC", command=btn_click("AC"))
btn_clear.grid(row= 1, column=0)

btn_backspace = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "<", command= btn_click("<"))
btn_backspace.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn_eql = FunctionalButton(calculator, text="=", command=btn_click("="))
btn_eql.grid(row=5, column=3)

btn_add = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "+", command= btn_click("+"))
btn_add.grid(row= 1, column=3)

btn_subtract = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "-", command= btn_click("-"))
btn_subtract.grid(row= 2, column=3)

btn_mulitply = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "x", command= btn_click("x"))
btn_mulitply.grid(row= 3, column=3)

btn_divide = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "/", command= btn_click("/"), bg= "red")
btn_divide.grid(row= 4, column=3)

calculator.mainloop()
```

I tried to solve the problem by writing the following code but it seems weird:

```
#Instantiate LCDScreen Object
screen = LCDScreen(btn_click())
print(screen.receiver())
```

I expect when I clicked the one of the button(exp: 1) the value: 1 will be passed to the instance(`screen`) and getting the output that `receiver()` method is called.

Comment: I don't think you need the `btn_value` argument in `LCDScreen.__init__()`.  All the checking inside `__init__()` should be done inside `receiver()` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I don't know how to pass the return value from the btn_click while
> clicking a button instance and send it to the screen instance.

The problem can fix.

Don't use wildcard `from tkinter import *`. Use this `import tkinter as tk`, then prefix `tk.`

Delete all functions such as `add`, `minus`, `multiply`, `divide` and `equal`.

- In line 5, start at the beginning root window. `calculator = tk.Tk()`
- In line 8, declare variable and add `tk.StringVar()`.
- In line 9, add variable `expression = ""`
- In line 10, add variable `total`.
- In line 13, replace inside b`tn_click` function.
- Move clear function to line 20, In line 13, replace inside b`clear`
  function.
- In line 25, create `backspace` function.
- In line 30, create `backspace` function.
- In `NumberButton` and `FunctionalButton`, add lambda command keyword command= lambda:
  `btn_click`
  In line 161 for multiply, Don't use char "**x**".  Use Asterisk *****

You are ready to go.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

 
calculator = tk.Tk()
calculator.title("Calculator")

equation = tk.StringVar() 

expression = ""
total = ""

def btn_click(value):
    global expression
    expression = expression + str(value)
    equation.set(expression)
    print(value)
    return value

def clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""
    equation.set("")

def backspace(value):
    current = e.get()
    lenght = len(current)-1
    e.delete(lenght, END)
    
def equalpress():
    try:
        global expression
        global total
 
        total = str(eval(expression))
 
        equation.set(total)
 
        expression = ""
 
    except:
        #equation.set(total) 
        equation.set(" error ")
        expression = ""
    
digit_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "0", "."]
operator_list = ["+", "-", "x", "/"]
functional_command_list = ["AC", "<", "="]

#Entry interface
 
 
e = tk.Entry(calculator, textvariable=equation, width= 40, borderwidth= 5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=5)

class LCDScreen():
    operator = ""
    number = ""
    functional_command = ""
     

    def __init__(self, btn_value):
        if btn_value in digit_list:
            self.number = btn_value
            self.receiver(self.number)
            
            return
        else:
            if btn_value in operator_list:
                self.operator = btn_value
                self.receiver(self.operator)
                #return
            else:
                if btn_value in functional_command_list:
                    self.functional_command = btn_value
                    self.receiver(self.functional_command)
                    return
                else:
                    print("Invalid input")

    def receiver(btn_value):
        received_value = btn_value
        print("Receiver function called")
        return received_value


#Define NumberButton class
class NumberButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw['width'] = 1
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.grid(ipadx=110, ipady=4)


#Define FunctionalButton class
class FunctionalButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw['width'] = 7
        kw['fg'] = 'black'

    
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.grid(ipadx=110, ipady=4)

#ef btn_click(value):
   # print(value)
    #return value
    
#Instantiate LCDScreen Object
screen = LCDScreen
#print(screen.receiver())

#Instantiate Number Button Object
btn_1 = NumberButton(calculator, text="1", command= lambda: btn_click("1"))
btn_1.grid(row=4, column=0)

btn_2 = NumberButton(calculator, text="2", command= lambda: btn_click("2"))
btn_2.grid(row=4, column=1)

btn_3 = NumberButton(calculator, text="3", command= lambda: btn_click("3"))
btn_3.grid(row=4, column=2)

btn_4 = NumberButton(calculator, text="4", command= lambda: btn_click("4"))
btn_4.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn_5 = NumberButton(calculator, text="5", command= lambda: btn_click("5"))
btn_5.grid(row=3, column=1)

btn_6 = NumberButton(calculator, text="6", command= lambda: btn_click("6"))
btn_6.grid(row=3, column=2)

btn_7 = NumberButton(calculator, text="7", command= lambda: btn_click("7"))
btn_7.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn_8 = NumberButton(calculator, text="8", command= lambda: btn_click("8"))
btn_8.grid(row=2, column=1)

btn_9 = NumberButton(calculator, text="9", command= lambda: btn_click("9"))
btn_9.grid(row=2, column=2)

btn_0 = NumberButton(calculator, text="0", command= lambda: btn_click("0"))
btn_0.grid(row=5, column=1) 

btn_decimal = NumberButton(calculator, text= ".", command=lambda: btn_click("."))
btn_decimal.grid(row=1, column= 2)

btn_clear = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "AC", command=clear)
btn_clear.grid(row= 1, column=0)

btn_backspace = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "<", command=lambda: backspace('<'))
btn_backspace.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn_eql = FunctionalButton(calculator, text="=", command=equalpress, bg= "red")
btn_eql.grid(row=5, column=3)

btn_add = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "+", command=lambda: btn_click("+"))
btn_add.grid(row= 1, column=3)

btn_subtract = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "-", command=lambda:  btn_click("-"))
btn_subtract.grid(row= 2, column=3)

btn_mulitply = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "x", command=lambda:  btn_click("*"))
btn_mulitply.grid(row= 3, column=3)

btn_divide = FunctionalButton(calculator, text= "/", command=lambda:  btn_click("/") )
btn_divide.grid(row= 4, column=3)

calculator.mainloop()
```

Screenshot for add, minus, multiply, divide and backspace.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error lies with your code here:

```
#Instantiate LCDScreen Object
screen = LCDScreen(btn_click())
```

You intent to "connect" the btn_click function to your class LCDScreen, so every time a button is pressed, a value is passed to a function of your LCDScreen object. However, this code here creates an instance of the LCDScreen class and calls its `__init__` function with the return value of `btn_click()`. This only happens once.

What you need is a function inside your LCDScreen class, which can be called from your button events, called `on_click()` in this example:

```
from tkinter import *


def btn_click(value):
    print(value)
    return value


digit_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "0", "."]
operator_list = ["+", "-", "x", "/"]
functional_command_list = ["AC", "<", "="]

# Entry interface
calculator = Tk()
calculator.title("Calculator")
e = Entry(calculator, width=40, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=5)


class LCDScreen():
    def __init__(self):  #variable initialization within init
        self.operator = ""
        self.number = ""
        self.functional_command = ""

    def on_click(self, btn_value):  
        if btn_value in digit_list:
            self.number = btn_value
            self.receiver(self.number)
            return
        elif btn_value in operator_list: #used elif here to improve readibility
            self.operator = btn_value
            self.receiver(self.operator)
            return
        elif btn_value in functional_command_list:
            self.functional_command = btn_value
            self.receiver(self.functional_command)
            return
        else:
            print("Invalid input")

    def receiver(self, btn_value):
        received_value = btn_value
        print(f"Receiver function called: {btn_value}")
        return received_value


# Define NumberButton class
class NumberButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw['width'] = 1
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.grid(ipadx=110, ipady=4)


# Define FunctionalButton class
class FunctionalButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw['width'] = 7
        kw['fg'] = 'black'

        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.grid(ipadx=110, ipady=4)


# Instantiate LCDScreen Object
screen = LCDScreen()

# Instantiate Number Button Object
btn_1 = NumberButton(calculator, text="1", command=lambda: screen.on_click("1"))
btn_1.grid(row=4, column=0)

btn_2 = NumberButton(calculator, text="2", command=lambda: screen.on_click("2"))
btn_2.grid(row=3, column=0)

calculator.mainloop()
```

You can now call the `on_click` function of your LCDScreen object `screen` with your button press and pass its respective value:

```
btn_1 = NumberButton(calculator, text="1", command=lambda: screen.on_click("1"))
btn_1.grid(row=4, column=0)
```